# Bootstrap convert spacing mixin from sass to less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a site running Bootstrap 3.3.7. I use less to adjust the styling. In version 4 of Bootstrap sass is introduced instead of less, and I noticed a new mixin which adds the ability to easily use predefined paddings and margins:

```
// Width

.w-100 { width: 100% !important; }

// Margin and Padding

.m-x-auto {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left:  auto !important;
}

@each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
  @each $size, $lengths in $spacers {
    $length-x:   map-get($lengths, x);
    $length-y:   map-get($lengths, y);

    .#{$abbrev}-a-#{$size} { #{$prop}:        $length-y $length-x !important; } // a = All sides
    .#{$abbrev}-t-#{$size} { #{$prop}-top:    $length-y !important; }
    .#{$abbrev}-r-#{$size} { #{$prop}-right:  $length-x !important; }
    .#{$abbrev}-b-#{$size} { #{$prop}-bottom: $length-y !important; }
    .#{$abbrev}-l-#{$size} { #{$prop}-left:   $length-x !important; }

    // Axes
    .#{$abbrev}-x-#{$size} {
      #{$prop}-right:  $length-x !important;
      #{$prop}-left:   $length-x !important;
    }
    .#{$abbrev}-y-#{$size} {
      #{$prop}-top:    $length-y !important;
      #{$prop}-bottom: $length-y !important;
    }
  }
}

// Positioning

.pos-f-t {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $zindex-navbar-fixed;
}
```

[Source at GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_spacing.scss)

I would like to convert this mixin to less, and use it in my own Bootstrap 3.3.7 project. How would this mixin look like in less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less does not have any `@each` function or `map` like Sass does but even then converting this Sass code into its Less equivalent is fairly easy. All that is needed are a couple of loops each of which will mimic the two `@each` function in Sass and associative arrays.

In Less, we can use both ***comma*** and ***space*** as delimiters for values. So by using both of them we can achieve a behavior similar to that of maps. Even multi-level maps can be mimicked using this.

(**Note:** You need to know the basics of Less loops to understand this code but since you've already used Less, I assume that you are familiar with the concepts. If not, have a look at docs)

```css
@props: margin m, padding p; /* the property and abbreviation */
@spacers: xs 10px 20px, md 20px 30px; /* the sizes, its length-x and length-y */

.loop-props(@prop-index) when (@prop-index > 0){ /* outer each loop */

  @prop: extract(@props, @prop-index); /* get each prop-abbrev pair based on loop index */
  @prop-name: extract(@prop, 1); /* the first value in each pair is the prop name */
  @abbrev: extract(@prop, 2); /* the second value in each pair is the prop's abbrev */

  /* call size loop mixin with each property name + abbreviation */
  .loop-sizes(@prop-name; @abbrev; length(@spacers)); 

  .loop-props(@prop-index - 1); /* call the next iteration of the outer each loop */
}
.loop-props(length(@props)) !important; /* initial mixin/loop call */

.loop-sizes(@prop-name; @abbrev; @size-index) when (@size-index > 0){ /* inner each */

  @spacer: extract(@spacers, @size-index); /* extract each spacer value based on index */
  @size: extract(@spacer, 1); /* first value in each spacer is the size */
  @x: extract(@spacer, 2); /* second value is the length in X axis */
  @y: extract(@spacer, 3); /* third value is the length in Y axis */

  /* create the selectors and properties using interpolation */
  .@{abbrev}-a-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}: @y @x; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-t-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-top: @y; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-r-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-right: @x; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-b-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-bottom: @y; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-l-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-left: @x; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-x-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-right: @x; 
    @{prop-name}-left: @x; 
  }
  .@{abbrev}-y-@{size} { 
    @{prop-name}-top: @y; 
    @{prop-name}-bottom: @y; 
  }

  .loop-sizes(@prop-name; @abbrev; @size-index - 1); /* call next iteration */
}
```

As you'd have noticed, I have attached the `!important` to the mixin call itself instead of attaching it each property. When this is done, the Less compiler automatically attaches the `!important` to every property and so we needn't repeat it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.  :-)

I only get this output with your code:

`p-a-md {
  padding: 30 20 !important;
}
.p-t-md {
  padding-top: 30 !important;
}
.p-r-md {
  padding-right: 20 !important;
}
.p-b-md {
  padding-bottom: 30 !important;
}
.p-l-md {
  padding-left: 20 !important;
}
.p-x-md {
  padding-right: 20 !important;
  padding-left: 20 !important;
}
.p-y-md {
  padding-top: 30 !important;
  padding-bottom: 30 !important;
}` I would expect the output to be like https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css from line 5889.

Comment: @Meek: Are you using the latest Less compiler? I've tried the code in the [official compiler](http://lesscss.org/less-preview) and it seems to work fine. Ofcourse, the units have to be added. I hadn't done that.

Comment: I'm using grunt with the lastest less compiler. Where should I add the units?

Comment: @Meek: The units can be directly added in the variable declaration line (like `@spacers: xs 1rem 2rem, md 2rem 3rem;`)